# Dict merge in a dict comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax-error, python-3.5, dict-comprehension

In python 3.5, we can merge dicts by using double-splat unpacking

```
>>> d1 = {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}
>>> d2 = {3: 'three'}
>>> {**d1, **d2}
{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}
```

Cool.  It doesn't seem to generalise to dynamic use cases, though:

```
>>> ds = [d1, d2]
>>> {**d for d in ds}
SyntaxError: dict unpacking cannot be used in dict comprehension
```

Instead we have to do `reduce(lambda x,y: {**x, **y}, ds, {})`, which seems a lot uglier.  Why the "one obvious way to do it" is not allowed by the parser, when there doesn't seem to be any ambiguity in that expression?

Comment: You can't do that in any other *- or **-unpacking context either.  I.e., you can't do `some_function(*x for x in list_lists)`.  The unpacking stars aren't real operators and can't occur in expressions.

Comment: `{k: v for d in [d1, d2] for k, v in d.items()}` would be an alternative to your `reduce()`, though "uglier" still.

Comment: I believe yet another alternative is `dict(ChainMap(d2, d1))` which I personally don't like because who the hell knows what a `ChainMap` is anyway?

Comment: Actually, just `ChainMap(*ds)` seems to be good enough on its own!  Nice, you should add that as an answer.

Comment: @wim you could edit the question to state that `ChainMap` is acceptable, saying "I want a view of merged dictionaries", "currently I am merging the dictionaries to create a new one"

Comment: also, you need to reverse the arguments to `ChainMap` (first found is used)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Good point, I'll make that clear in my answer.

Comment: Sigh.... `{**d for d in ds}` would have been really nice.

Comment: Related: https://bugs.python.org/issue2292

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's not exactly an answer to your question but I'd consider using [`ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) to be an idiomatic and elegant way to do what you propose (merging dictionaries in-line):

```
>>> from collections import ChainMap
>>> d1 = {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}
>>> d2 = {3: 'three'}
>>> ds = [d1, d2]
>>> dict(ChainMap(*ds))
{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}
```

Although it's not a particularly transparent solution, since many programmers might not know exactly how a `ChainMap` works. Note that (as @AnttiHaapala points out) "first found is used" so, depending on your intentions you might need to make a call to `reversed` before passing your `dict`s into `ChainMap`.

```
>>> d2 = {3: 'three', 2: 'LOL'}
>>> ds = [d1, d2]
>>> dict(ChainMap(*ds))
{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}

>>> dict(ChainMap(*reversed(ds)))
{1: 'one', 2: 'LOL', 3: 'three'}
```

Answer (score 19):

To me, the obvious way is:

```
d_out = {}
for d in ds:
    d_out.update(d)
```

This is quick and probably quite performant.  I don't know that I can speak for the python developers, but I don't know that your expected version is more easy to read.  For example, your comprehension looks more like a set-comprehension to me due to the lack of a `:`.  FWIW, I don't think there is any *technical* reason (e.g. parser ambiguity) that they *couldn't* add that form of comprehension unpacking.

Apparently, [these forms were proposed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/#variations), but didn't have universal enough support to warrant implementing them (yet).

Comment: By making it an expression instead of a statement, the possible use-cases are increased for functional styles.  If the for loop was always better, there would be no reason to add the merging expression at all - my question is more about why it was intentionally limited to a known predetermined number of operands?

Comment: @wim -- If you really want a to do this in a functional approach, just wrap this in a function :-).  As discussed in the relevant PEP, the reason that it was intentionally limited was because there wasn't strong enough consensus in the community about what syntax to use.  Perhaps it will be revisited at some time in the future, but for now, it was omitted so that the parts that everyone did agree on could be scheduled for implemenation.

Comment: Funnily enough the comprehension syntax was [part of the implementation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/#implementation) and got actively removed.

Comment: @norok2  I still can not see any convincing reason for why it was removed (?)

Answer (score 5):

Idiomatic, *without* `ChainMap`:

```
>>> d1 = {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}
>>> d2 = {3: 'three'}
>>> {k: v for d in [d1, d2] for k, v in d.items()}
{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) or `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```py
import itertools

ds = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 30, 'b': 40}]

merged_d = dict(itertools.chain(*(d.items() for d in ds)))
print(merged_d)  # {'a': 1, 'b': 40, 'c': 30}
```

Comment: And how do I unpack it in the same line (before attributing to merged_d)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this solution](https://datagy.io/python-merge-dictionaries/#Merge-Python-Dictionaries-with-a-Dictionary-Comprehension-) and also mentioned by @ilgia-everilä, but making it Py2 compatible and still avoiding intermediate structures. Encapsulating it inside a function makes its use quite readable.

```py
def merge_dicts(*dicts, **extra):
    """
    >>> merge_dicts(dict(a=1, b=1), dict(b=2, c=2), dict(c=3, d=3), d=4, e=4)
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 4}
    """
    return dict((
        (k,v)
        for d in dicts
        for k,v in d.items()
    ), **extra)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define this function:

```
from collections import ChainMap
def mergeDicts(l):
    return dict(ChainMap(*reversed(list(l))))
```

You can then use it like this:

```
>>> d1 = {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}
>>> d2 = {3: 'three'}
>>> ds = [d1, d2]
>>> mergeDicts(ds)
{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}
```