# Turning nested for loop into dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, dictionary-comprehension

How would I turn this into dictionary comprehension?

```
dict_ = defaultdict(int)
 for sequence in set_sequence:
  for ele in sequence:
   dict_[ele] += 1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37585628/14237276 is one.  the other is to do update calls inside [] and discard the list

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested comprehension, with `Counter`:

```py
from collections import Counter

set_sequence = [['a','b','b'], ['b', 'c', 'c']]
dict_ = Counter(ele for sequence in set_sequence for ele in sequence)
print(dict_) # Counter({'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'a': 1})
```